# Haskell: Return Nothing in case of exception

Tags: haskell, try-catch, option-type

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Typeable
import Control.Exception

data EmptyListException = EmptyListException
    deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception EmptyListException

myHead :: [a] -> a
myHead []    = throw EmptyListException
myHead (x:_) = x

mySafeHead :: [a] -> IO (Maybe a)
mySafeHead xs = (return (Just (myHead xs)))
                `catch`
                (\(ex::EmptyListException) -> return Nothing)
```

I want to return the first element of xs if there is one.
Otherwise I want to return "Nothing", but it returns the Exception wrapped in "Just".
Why is that?
P.S.: I have to use `myHead` in `mySaveHead`.

Comment: This assignment is a silly assignment. Really. Intentionally throwing exceptions in pure code is a bad idea in almost all cases.

Comment: Maybe it is not intentional? Maybe it just models something that is given and has its own good reasons to throw exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So when I run your code, this is what I see

```
λ mySafeHead []
Just *** Exception: EmptyListException
```

I understand why you'd describe this as "it returns the Exception wrapped in "Just".", but that's not actually what's going on.

Haskell is non-strict, so it postpones computation until a value is demanded.

In `mySafeHead` the value of `myHead xs` is not examined, so it isn't evaluated. Instead, the computation for that value is left as a *thunk*, which is wrapped in `Just` and returned.

Then, in `ghci`, that thunk is finally forced when trying to print the value, and an exception is raised. Since we're now well outside the scope of the `catch` statement, it doesn't apply, and the exception makes it all the way to the terminal, where it interrupts the printing of the output.

The easy way to fix this is to use `seq` to force evaluation of `myHead xs` before exiting the `catch` statement:

```
mySafeHead' :: [a] -> IO (Maybe a)                             
mySafeHead' xs = (let x = myHead xs in x `seq` return (Just x))
                `catch`                                        
                (\(_::EmptyListException) -> return Nothing)
```

`seq` takes two arguments - it returns the second, but only after forcing the first to Weak Head Normal Form (WHNF), that is, after finding out what the outermost constructor is. This forces `x` sufficiently for the `EmptyListException` to be raised, so `catch` can do its thing:

```
λ mySafeHead' []
Nothing
```

Comment: Weird, [I cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb745837390c831b) your initial output.

Comment: Angry Shoe: never used that site before, so not sure why it's working different than on my machine (maybe it doesn't flush STDOUT when it exits with an error?), but [you can see the `Just` constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d41f9ac659b08e) with a little pattern matching.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `evaluate` for catching exceptions while executing pure computations:

```
mySafeHead :: [a] -> IO (Maybe a)
mySafeHead xs = mySafeHead' xs `catch` handler
    where  
        mySafeHead' :: [a] -> IO (Maybe a)
        mySafeHead' ls = do
            x <- evaluate $ myHead ls
            return $ Just x
        handler :: EmptyListException -> IO (Maybe a)
        handler ex = return Nothing
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b30c74b39dc59be2)

Comment: But then the resulting computation is impure (`IO` monad).

Comment: @immibis Catching an exception must be in in IO anyways... so you don't really lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to get the head of a list as `Just a` when the
list is non-empty, otherwise `Nothing`, the sensible approach is
not to use exceptions at all (whether explicitly thrown by you, or
thrown as a result of calling `head :: [a] -> a` on an empty list).  Instead, define a *total function*:

```
mySafeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
mySafeHead [] = Nothing
mySafeHead (a:_) = Just a
```

Alternatively, use [`headMay`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.9/docs/Safe.html#v:headMay) from the *safe* package.

The existence of non-total functions in the `Prelude` such as `head` and `tail` is an historical mistake.  Hopefully one day they will be deprecated and, eventually, removed.